# Regarding wait in Linux C programming

Tags: c, linux, exit

I was given this code to run on Linux and its output was

```
 S=512 P=0
```

I didn't understand why when we passed the memory address of the variable S to exit, it became a multiple of 256*S.

A few experiments I tried: I set S=1 and the output was 256, I entered S=256, the output was S=0 and when I entered S=-1, the output was 256*255

Note: I am used to C++ and haven't used C much.

```
 int s=2, p=fork();

  if (p) {

    p -= wait(&s);

        printf("s=%d p=%d\n", s, p);

  }

  else

        exit(s);
```

Comment: Reading the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) carefully usually helps: "If status is not NULL, wait() and waitpid() store status information in the int to which it points. **This integer can be inspected with the following macros**". That is, wait does not give you the exit status value directly.

Comment: `wait()` is storing termination information into `s` when you pass the address. One of the pieces of that information is the exit status (if it terminated normally). Another piece is how it was terminated, for example if it terminated normally via `exit()`, or if it was terminated by receipt of a signal. You have to use macros like `WIFEXITED()` and `WEXITSTATUS()` to interpret this information, it's not usually useful to examine the value directly.

Comment: Buy why 256, what does 256 signify or imply? and if it is storing information about termination, then why does it multiply with the previous value of S?

Comment: This code will do nothing, because it does not even compile. Why don't you ask whoever you got it from ?

Comment: @Olaf its just missing some headers, that's about it.

#include <stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

Comment: OK I have understood why it gives us 256: The exit code is a 16 bit value and the higher 8 bits are returned from exit() and the lower half are zeros when the process terminates normally, I still don't get why it multiplies the value of the integer S in my code with 256...